# Magento 2.3.0: Error when trying to generate shipment more than 3 products

Tags: admin, sales-order, magento2.3.0, shipment

When trying to make shipment of order having more than 3 products then it showing below error -

[image]

Anybody face this type of issue , please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your disk is full.

You can also check tabel status:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM db_name LIKE 'catalog_product_index_price_temp'
```

Reference:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/full-table.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table-size-limit.html

UPDATE:

After some diging on Magento issues:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6415

Comment: I observe this issue, and yes its an issue when disk is full, but what will be the max limit of extending memory when B2B client is making shipment for 100's of product ? I am looking for a solution to break this memory limit issue, thanks

Comment: Please check update, from Magento issues. This could be helpful on your case. I checked in mine and I have different name 'catalog_product_index_price_tmp' instead of temp

Comment: I gone through the give github solution , result found to extend memory